# Django get related objects ManyToMany relationships

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```py
class CartToys(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
        
class Cart(models.Model):
    cart_item = models.ManyToManyField(CartToys)
```

I want to get all related toys to this cart. how can I do this

Comment: Cart.objects.get(pk=1).carttoys_set.all()

Comment: Class CartToys should be named CartToy by convention.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you would use...

```
cart = Cart.objects.first()
objects = cart.cart_item.all() # this line return all related objects for CartToys
# and in reverse
cart_toy = CartToys.objects.first()
carts = cart_toy.cart_set.all() # this line return all related objects for Cart
```