# Django get ManyToMany variable in template

Tags: django, django-templates

i have to models linked with ManyToMany relation:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512)

class Task(models.Model):
    event = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank=True, related_name='tasks')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
```

in view.py i collect all user events by:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

now in template i want to display each event in loop with event-task.description

```
{% for event in events %}
    {{event.title}}
    {{event.task.description}}  ???
{% endfor %}
```

How to get this work?

Related questions: [link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140733/django-get-related-objects-manytomany-relationships), [link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144387/django-manytomany-show-related-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
{% for event in events %}
    {{event.title}}

    {% for task in event.tasks.all %}
        {{ task.description }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: solution is not working. In Django view can't access event.tasks in loop : 'Event' object has no attribute 'task'

Comment: "tasks" not "task" you declared this in your model `related_name="tasks"`

Comment: still i get empty data [empty Queryset]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.all`.Try the following:

```
{% for event in events %}
    {{event.title}}
    {% for task in event.event.all %}{{ task.description }}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: solution is not working. In Django view can't access event.tasks in loop : 'Event' object has no attribute 'task'

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi what do you mean by not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: no data is displayed and  can't access task by looping over events and getting task.description in view.py

Comment: Maybe the related name of tasks isn't working try the above with the name of the field itself

Comment: did you migrate your changes?

Comment: @kyore well it should be but we're missing something